# How to use iostat with AppleRAID volume?

Tags: macos, command-line, raid

When I try `iostat disk5`, I get the error:

```
iostat: could not record 'disk5' for monitoring
```

`Iostat` works with my other drives, and with the individual disks which make up the RAID volume.  How can I get the speed of disk5, which is an AppleRAID volume?

Answer (score 0):

BSD iostat - yeeeecchhhhh. There are some things that Gnu/Linux just does better.

What happens when you try `iostat -d -n 9` - that should give you an iostat on the first 9 drives hooked up (if you have 9 drives).

RAID is challenging since the OS reports them as several drives so you might have to do the math knowing the RAID level based on the reported data read / written or choose some tool like SoftRAID.

Comment: It omits the RAID volume, and it shows each of the 4 disks that make it up.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that. The drive system sees the physical disks not the logical drive. You may be stuck.