# macOS alternative for /sys/block/*/stat to get read and written sectors or bytes

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, activity-monitor, monitoring

I am searching for an alternative of Linux `/sys/block/*/stat` for macOS to get the number of sectors (or Bytes) read and written since system start for each drive.

Native commands like `iostat -I` give the  total blocks/sectors transferred, but it can not be differentiated how many blocks/sectors were read or written. `iotop` requires SIP to be turned off, what is not acceptable.

So far, I have not found any third-party packages that provide somehow the request functionally above.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the disk arguments to `iostat` would be the best I can suggest.

```
iostat -I -w 5 -n 9
```

The above lists the first nine drives and if you wish to reorder them, pick off the drive names from the above command and list them in order and omit the `-n 9`

```
iostat -I -w 5  disk7 disk5 disk0
```

To be fair, `iostat` [isn't well loved and comes from BSD lineage of macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/118501/5472) so it's not really a true equivalent of the linux implementation you seek.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But unfortunately this does not help me in my case.

Comment: understood @Elektronenhirn - there's no harm in not selecting an answer or coming back in a year or three and providing how you worked around whatever your end goal is with this data you seek to gather.